# How to get Java model object back from String object?

Tags: java, list, java-8

I have a model class:

```
public class Person{
    private String personnelId;
    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
}
```

Now I have service class

```
public class A{
    @Autowired
    private OfficerService officer;

    public List<Person> getAccounts(Param param){
        List<Person> personList = personDao.getAccounts(param);
        List<String> stringList = personList.stream().map(Person::getPersonnelId).collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<String> list = Officer.getVisiblePerson(stringList);
        List<Person> visiblePersonList= new ArrayList<>();

        return visiblePersonList;
    }
```

Now when I convert `List<Person>` into `List<String>` which gets the `personnelId` from Model class. After the method call I get back `personnelId`. I need to convert back into `List<Person>` which will contain all the data with `firstName` and `lastName` in `Person` class attached to that Id. How can I do that?

EDIT:

```
Map<String, Person> personMap = personList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getPersonnelId, person -> person));
    List<Person> visiblePersonList = list.stream()
        .map(id -> personMap.get(id))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I get an error on collect of map:

```
The method collect(Collector<? super String,A,R>) in the type Stream<String> is not applicable for the arguments (Collector<Person,capture#2-of ?,Map<String,Object>>)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is the conversion to `List<String>` really necessary?

Comment: If you want it as a model why did you convert it to a string?

Comment: Yeah im consuming some 3rd party service and that service only takes string.

Comment: What does `Officer.getVisiblePerson(...)` do?

Comment: 'Officer.getVisiblePerson(...)'  takes 'List<String>' of Ids, consumes 3rd party service and gives back 'List<String>' of Ids which are accessible to Officer in question from the Person Object. Is there a better way to do what I'm doing?

Comment: I wrote 
`Map<String, Person> personMap = personList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getPersonnelId, person -> person));

    List<Person> visiblePersonList = list.stream()
        .map(id -> personMap.get(id))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());`

But it gives me an error, 

`The method collect(Collector<? super String,A,R>) in the type Stream<String> is not applicable for the arguments (Collector<Person,capture#2-of ?,Map<String,Object>>)`

Answer (score 2):

One way to will be to have it in a map and then get these values from a map. There is one additional iteration , but depending on how big the list is or if it can be parallel , performance will be slightly more or less.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>(); // personDao.getAccounts(param);

    Person person1 = new Person("1", "ln1", "fn1");
    Person person2 = new Person("2", "ln2", "fn2");
    Person person3 = new Person("3", "ln3", "fn3");
    Person person4 = new Person("4", "ln4", "fn4");
    personList.add(person1);
    personList.add(person2);
    personList.add(person3);
    personList.add(person4);

/*Of interest , the logic*/
        List<String> stringList = personList.stream().map(Person::getPersonnelId).collect(Collectors.toList());
        Map<String, Person> mapStringToPerson = personList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getPersonnelId, person -> person));

/*as a logic filter even number id , in a real life this will be officer filter*/
            List<String> listFiltered = stringList.stream().filter(personId -> (Integer.parseInt(personId) % 2 == 0))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());// Officer.getVisiblePerson(stringList);
            List<Person> visiblePersonList = listFiltered.stream().filter(id -> mapStringToPerson.containsKey(id))
                    .map(id -> mapStringToPerson.get(id)).collect(Collectors.toList());
            visiblePersonList.forEach(System.out::println);

}
```

Prints ::

```
    Person with id : 2 and name fn2 ln2
    Person with id : 4 and name fn4 ln4
```

Answer (score 1):

First, let me address some naming issues:

- `Officer` should be `officer`.
- `stringList` should be named `idList`, since that's what it contains, conceptually. You don't name it for the type, because:

  1. You can see that by looking at ... *(you guessed it)* ... the type.
  2. Saying "String" is meaningless and says nothing about what the string represents.
- Similarly, `list` should be named `visibleIdList`.

Now I'll use the name I just suggested.

Since `getVisiblePerson()` returns a list of the entries from `idList` that are visible, i.e. a filtered list, you can do one of two things:

1. Create `Map<String, Person>` of `id` to `Person`, then iterate `visibleIdList` and lookup the `Person` and build a list of that.
2. Turn `visibleIdList` into a `visibleIdSet`, then iterate `personList` and filter to those in the `Set`.

Option 2 has a smaller memory footprint, and likely better performance too.